# how do I get adapter size to be correctly reflected in my onQueryTextChange?

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

When a user types in my `searchbox` I use `onQueryTextChange` so the text is filtered and either:

1) a `"No Results"` textbox should be shown - if nothing typed matches the `items` in my list.

2) The matching `items` are shown in my `recyclerView`.

For the most part it is working ok but sometimes it is like the `onQueryTextChange` is a step behind.

For example, "plumber" is one of the `items` in my list, the only `item` beginning with "p"

The user types "p" in `searchbox`, "plumber" appears in my `recyclerView` - yet I get the toast "mAdapter size is: 13". 13 is the whole number of `items`, `mAdapter` size should be just 1.

When I type "pl" the `toast` for `mAdapter` is correct, it shows 1.

When I type "plk" the `toast` for `mAdapter` is wrong, it still shows 1 - it should say, `"mAdapter is 0, no item results"` and instead of the `recyclerView` we should see the `"No Results"` textbox.

It's only when I type the next character, like `"plke"`, that I see `"mAdapter is 0, no item results"` and the `"No Results"` textbox.

Here's my code:

```
@Override
      public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {

          //items is the complete list of the category names available to the logged-in user
          items = new Gson().fromJson(the_response, new TypeToken<List<Category>>() {
          }.getType());

          //clear the list every time a key is pressed
          categoryList.clear();

          //was getting NullPointerException so put this here...
          if (items != null && items.size() > 0) {
            //adding categories to category list
            categoryList.addAll(items);
          }

          mAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);

          recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

          if (mAdapter.getItemCount() < 1) {

            //if there's nothing to show, hide recyclerView...
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            //and show the "No Results" textbox
            noResultsFoundView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "mAdapter is 0, no item results", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }

        if (mAdapter.getItemCount() >= 1) {

            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            noResultsFoundView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            //if there ARE category results for what is typed, with each key press...
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "mAdapter size is:" + mAdapter.getItemCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


          }

          //if the searchView is empty
          if (searchView.getQuery().length() == 0) {

            //show the logged-in users reviews, not the searched categories
            recyclerView.setAdapter(pAdapter);
            pAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            //show the recyclerview, hide the noResults textview
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            noResultsFoundView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

          }

          // refreshing recycler view
          mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        return false;

      }
```

Comment: use an adapter that implements `Filterable` interface like [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/cd3bbdd742b5b1905a790c76831b5d85) one and override `matches()` method

Comment: I use this adapter that implements Filterable : https://www.androidhive.info/2017/11/android-recyclerview-with-search-filter-functionality/, works ok apart from the adapter not being updated just when text changes.

Comment: so it does not work ok, see [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/07mBMT0t) sample usage

Comment: also `MatchableRVArrayAdapter` is a generic one so you dont have to write it from the scratch every time you need a new adapter

Comment: Ok. I am not too sure what you mean - new to this - but will look into it.

Comment: i mean that all you have to do is to write `class Adapter extends MatchableRVArrayAdapter<YourDataModel> { ...` and just override two methods, thats all